Где здесь ошибка? (При вводе номера вылетает
eyegod_number.csv
{+} id
{+} Number
{+} First name
{+} Last name

Код
Write.Print(Center.XCenter(menu), Colors.red_to_purple, interval=0.005)
         
select = input(f'{color_code["red"]}:)')

if select == '1':
    input("Поиск по номеру телефона")

def find_rows_with_substring(file_path, substring):
 if not os.path.exists(file_path): print(f"Файл {file_path} не найден! Выполнение поиска  невозможно!")
 else:
   with open(file_path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
         reader = csv.reader(eyegod_number.csv)
   header = next(reader)
   [print(row) for row in reader if any(substring.lower() in cell.lower() for cell in row)]
   while True:
         substring = input("\nУкажите строку  для поиска: ")
   if not substring: print("Не указана подстрока для выполнения поиска! Попробуйте ще раз!")
   else:
       find_rows_with_substring("eyegod_number.csv", substring)

Хочу создать программу для Termux в которой пользователь написав номер телефона получил бы полную строку из таблицы eyegod_number.csv . Но при вводе номера телефона просто вылетает [Program Finished]

Так а где вы вызываете функцию find_rows_with_substring? Она только сама из себя вызывается, но сначала её как-то из основного кода нужно вызвать.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Поиск ошибок, которые нельзя воспроизвести => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Забыли кавычки поставить в названии файла.
reader = csv.reader('eyegod_number.csv')

Также переменная reader создается в контексте with и исчезает сразу после with. Исправить можно так:
else:
   reader = csv.reader(eyegod_number.csv)
   header = next(reader) 

В вашем коде файл читается с помощью reader и with в этом не участвует.
